# Possible encoding mismatch from iOS Client

Tags: ios, http, encoding, content-type, emoji

I've got an iOS application, and we've been getting some errors that seem to be related to encoding problems because some of content is getting truncated when it reaches the server. This is problematic because it's been messing with our authentication mechanism, which involves making a hash of the posted content (along with some other stuff, but that's the basics).

So far we haven't been able to reproduce the problem locally. We have a theory that it's related to something like, an emoji keyboard; but I've tried posting emojis, international characters, everything that I could think of. Everything gets posted correctly when I try it. I know that there was a difference in the way ios encodes emoji between ios 4 and 5; we've managed to speak with a few of our customers to try to get an idea about what they're using, and it's usually iOS 6, with either an iphone 4s, or 5 (just like our test devices, I've tested with ios 5 and 6) ... so it wouldn't seem to be related to the OS.

This is how we are setting the request's body for the post.

```
[req setHTTPBody:[paramString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Previously, I was just setting the content-type to this:

```
[req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

And my theory is that being explicit about the charset in the content type might fix it:

```
[req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

So my question for you SO, is this crazy? do you think being explicit in setting the charset to UTF-8 would resolve the issue? Any other troubleshooting techniques that you can recommend to figure out where the problem is occurring?

Comment: Do you have an example of the server log? Does the text get truncated (which would point to a buffer size problem) or mangled (possible encoding problem)? Any server errors you are seeing? Which HTTP client library are you using?

Comment: HTTP should be UTF-8 by default. So unless you have strange server settings, setting the charset explicitly should not make a difference.

Comment: @fishinear I don't have an example of a server log readily available, but basically we know that it was truncated because we actually called a user on the phone and asked her what she sent. All of the content did not come through ... But as I mentioned, I've tried to reproduce it with long content, and content with every kind of odd character I could think of.

Comment: @fishinear we're not seeing any platform server errors, only in our authentication mechanism where the hash of the content generated by the client doesn't match what the server generates when it receives the content. This is probably because the content used by the client to generate the hash has the full text, but at some point between when we generate that hash (which is right before making the post with NSMutableUrl) and the time it arrives at the server, the content changes. I'm not doing much that I can see would change it on the client.

Comment: @JoelMartinez are these problematic clients possibly behind proxies? I am in China, and your question brings a lot of bad memory of our old projects, which is caused by misbehaving proxies, and this is typical for a lot of mobile carriers here. So in the end, we base64 encoded everything before sending it to the air.

Comment: @JerryTian interesting theory ... I had considered that, but was not sure if there was any way to validate that theory. But at least it's good to know that it's a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a wireshark or fiddler trace of a failing request? I would start there to verify that the client is indeed sending truncated data, and it's not a server side issue.

Check that the `Content-Length` header is correct regardless of data sent. Since the issue is not easily reproducible, perhaps collect more specific data from users who saw the problem, so the problematic inputs can be identified, and the broken request can be reproduced repeatedly.

I doubt it's an encoding issue if you are pulling strings straight from a UITextField, you shouldn't have encoding issues. If you are going to/from CStrings or NSData then that would be the first place to check.

Not a conclusive answer by any means, but that's where I would start.

Comment: No, unfortunately these errors have only been seen "in the wild", so I don't have nearly as much data as I'd like. I've never been able to identify a sequence of characters that caused it, we only know because we started logging occurrences of this error on the server when encountered. Yes, I was planning on introducing a troubleshooting piece that, when the error occurs on the clientside, will ask the user to send us an email that would contain the contents that they tried to submit.